# Automating Facebook wall posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I was wondering if you could help me - with PHP, I would like to have a system where after going through a like-gate, the customer uploads a file (I'm fine with doing this) and once they have done that the application will write a post on the users wall to tell them.

As a second stage to this, when in the admin tool for the app, the administrator puts a comment against the image that person has uploaded, we'd like the comment to go onto the customers wall - and this might be a week after.

Any help gratefully appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the Graph API http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

You will need permissions from the user: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ Specifically `publish_stream`.

Posting to someone's wall is easy.  From `me/posts` HTTP Post the correct parameters. See the post section of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

You can try it out here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer